# How to change the root definitions folder location for Google Cloud Dataform project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform

I have several Dataform projects which have a similar functionality. They are deployed to different GCP projects.

I want to keep them in one git repository, because most of the changes are reflected in all of them almost similarly, and it is easy to manage.

As a side note, I have another git repo for Airflow dags, which I also want to combine into one git repo with Dataform code.

I imagine the following git repo structure:

```
dags/
  ...
dataform/
  project_A/
    definitions/
    dataform.json
  project_B/
    definitions/
    dataform.json
```

What are the ways to achieve this?